# How to create a product's category which is visible ONLY after logging in?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, products

A client of mine wants me to create a group of products which could be seen only to registered users. I mean: if you are not logged in, you can not see this category (but you can navigate inside the site and see all the other products), when you are logged in instead you can see also the hidden one. 
That's not the right place to explain all the reasons why he would like to have this kind of thing, but that's it. :(

Can anybody help me?

Comment: i will give you solution tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you given this extension a try?

> Groups Catalog 2 - https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

It allows you to hide categories and products from customers based on their group. So it sounds like it can help you to achieve what you're looking for (and maybe even more than you expected).

Otherwise, if you want to go commando and figure this out for yourself, I can try to give a few pointers.

- Catalog visibility is controlled by `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category::canShow`
- Product visibility, by `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::canShow`

These methods are called in routes like category views (eg: `catalog/category/view/id/1`) which resolve to `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::viewAction`. This method will first attempt to initialize the category model in the `_initAction` method. And, as you will see here, visibility is verified:

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php
...
protected function _initCatagory()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_controller_category_init_before', array('controller_action' => $this));
    $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
    if (!$categoryId) {
        return false;
    }

    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load($categoryId);

    if (!Mage::helper('catalog/category')->canShow($category)) {
        return false;
    }
...
```

So if the `canShow` method from the category helper returns false, then the controller will forward the request to `noRoute`, which is the 404 error page.

Why I'm getting at this is to illustrate the purposes of  `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category::canShow`. By re-writing this method in your own module, you could add additional logic to match the category ID against what's actually visible to the currently logged in user, eg:

```
# File: app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Helper/Category.php
# Method: Namespace_Module_Helper_Catalog::canShow
...
// @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
// @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
if (!in_array($category->getId(), $customer->getVisibleCategories())) {
    return false;
}
...
```

Where `visible_categories` is an attribute that you expand into an array for validating against the given category. This probably isn't an ideal solution, but it gives you an idea of where to go.

In order to extend that method, you'll have to setup a helper rewrite in your module:

```
# File: app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml
...
<helpers>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <category>Namespace_Module_Helper_Category</category>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</helpers>
...
```

Of course, first give the extension I mentioned above a try. It has been written and maintained by expert Magento developers who knew how to cover all bases with this sort of thing.

Comment: Any idea how to acheive it via restAPI

Comment: REST for Magento 1? Custom endpoint? Extension of core category endpoint? 

Not enough information. Generally the M1 REST API does not work well here (is this a headless build). However, when you want to pull categories restricted by a customer, you probably need to extend `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Category_Rest::_getCategoryIds` to restrict by some customer data passed in. Or, extend `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product::getCategoryCollection` in some way to look for persisted customer data. Best to ask this as a new question.

Comment: its magento 2.3.

Comment: Then you should post it as a new question and tag as Magento 2. The answer provided here won't help you at all.